# Gradient color matrix from matrix of integers

Tags: matrix, gradient

I have a matrix of a game map. The matrix is `int[][]` and the values in this matrix represent the height of the terrain.

Is there any algorithm to make gradient color matrix from this matrix of height?

I mean a transfer like this:

```
int[][] gameMap -> Color[][] colorGradient;
```

After this transfer I will color each pixel of map:

```
setPixelColor(i, j, colorGradient[i][j]);
```

My try:

```
                for each map i ,j
                int value = gameMap[i][j] - min;

                float aa = max - min; //(max value on map and min value on map)

                float percent = value / (aa / 100);

                gameMapColorMap[i][j] = Color.getHSBColor(0f, percent / 10 , 0.30f);
```

Comment: @elhefe: Sorry, I edit my post.

Comment: Does that work? If not, what's the problem? If it does, what's the question?